# Static resource are conflicting with @PathParam in Spring boot with thymleaf localhost:8080/script.js is conflicting with localhost:8080/{message}

Tags: spring-boot

Main Class-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller Class

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/{message}")
    public String greeting(@PathVariable(name="message", required=false) String message, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", message);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

Html File

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${message} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

Script File

```
console.log("hi");
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Get your greeting <a href="/greeting">here</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[Find Screenshot of Directory Structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP8Wu.png)

Moreover, this project reference is from https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ with below modification

- In `GreetingController` instead of `query param` accepting parameter
  through `path param`
- Added a script file to `/resources/static` folder
- In `greeting.html` added one line to include `script file`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
```

Instead of

```
<link href="/script.js" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: didn't worked... actually it's conflicting /script.js is getting treated as localhost:8080/script.js and script.js is received as city and instead of returning js file spring is returning home view

Comment: I have updated the initial question for better clarity could you please check

Answer (score 0):

You better post full home.html file and full Controller class. 
OR 
Try @PathVariable instead of @PathParam . As @PathParam can use with REST only, where @PathVariable used in Spring so it works in MVC and REST.

Comment: I have updated the initial question for better clarity could you please check